# How do I stay logged in on Safari 12?

Tags: safari, login, mojave

Since upgrading to Safari 12, many sites that I could remain logged into for extended periods of time now aggressively log me out, often several times a day. Sometimes it even becomes difficult to successfully log back in again.

Sites where I have this issue include Amazon (both the store and AWS), SE sites, G Suite, Facebook, GitHub, and many other major sites. Typically logging in again requires reentering two-factor authentication, even if this has been disabled for Safari (with "don't ask again", or "trust"). Other sites (e.g., Wikipedia, The Guardian) have no trouble keeping me logged in, even with ad blockers fully enabled.

My Safari privacy settings are:

[image]

How do I stay logged in on Safari 12? What's changed or what do I need to change to get the old behavior back?

Comment: I have dozens of sites where the cookies persist for 14 days or more on Safari 12. https://portal.office.com and https://icloud.com and this site are just a few that work well. Would you be willing to edit in a specific site where this fails? Also - list any content blockers as many sites are acting either hostile or punitive to people when they detect you not allowing JS to run crazy on your web browser. Apple is seriously ratcheting down on insecure practices and cross site scripts, so your side question of how to get the old behavior back is basically - load Safari 11.

Comment: @bmike: Added some examples. Basically it's pretty widespread. I use ABP as a an ad blocker, but on the sites listed I've disabled it, and unchecked "Enable content blockers" for the site in Safari settings.

Comment: Great edits. I’ll try to test in aws and let you know. With that many sites, something’s clearly up that you’re seeing.

Comment: I have the same issue with some sites and not others. After I upgraded to Mojave Google and YouTube stayed logged-in. I then reset Safari in at attempt to fix other websites, now Google and YouTube also get logged out in five minutes no matter how actively I use them.

Comment: @bmike: Any insights? Safari is basically unusable for me now. 12 seems to be completely broken and in need of an update to address what appears to be a serious bug with cookies.

Comment: This has been a problem for me too on lots of sites, including StackExchange sites. Has anyone come up with a fix?

Comment: @JScarry The 12 update seems to have broken Safari. I expect Apple knows this and is not commenting as usual while they try to fix it. Whether the fix will also restore some degree of ad blocking is anyone’s guess (my bet is that they are now colluding with advertisers and that reliable ad blocking is a thing of the past — until Apple is adequately regulated).

Comment: It has been like this since Mojave beta for me. There is no fix. It only affects one iCloud account on one device. New accounts on the same device work fine, as do new devices with the same iCloud account. But on this particular device, signing into iCloud on a new account immediately triggers the issue on Safari. Safari Technology Preview on the same account with iCloud works fine.

Comment: Do any of you have the Tampermonkey installed?

Comment: @Monstieur No (and some more characters)

Comment: I updated to macOS beta with Safari 13 and the problem still persists. However Safari Technology Preview 13 works fine. It seems to be related to the default "Safari.app".

Comment: macOS Catalina has resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Update: macOS Catalina has resolved the issue for me.

The only workaround as of now is to use Safari Technology Preview. If you delete all Safari folders from your home directory, you can stay logged in to the first few websites you visit. After this initial period, it starts deleting cookies for all future websites.